# matplotlib.pyplot.ticklabel_format has no effect on the figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, format

as the title suggests, this is a straightforward question: ticklabel_format simply has no effect whatsoever on my figure.
here's the script:

```
import sys
import math
import yaml
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
dwarf  = sys.argv[1]
pts = np.empty([100,100])
fig = plt.figure()
fig.suptitle('J value - %s'%dwarf,fontsize=18)
m = plt.imshow(pts,cmap='rainbow',extent=[-2,2,5,9])
plt.xlabel(r'$r_s [kpc]$',fontsize=18)
plt.ylabel(r'$\rho_s [M_{sun} kpc^{-3}]$',fontsize=18)
plt.ticklabel_format(style='sci',axis='x',scilimits=(-2,2))
plt.ticklabel_format(style='sci',axis='y',scilimits=(5,9))
plt.grid()
cx = plt.colorbar(m,pad=0)
cx.set_label(r'$log_{10}(J(\rho_s,r_s))$',fontsize=18)
plt.savefig('output/gridJ_%s.png'%dwarf,dpi=100,format='png')
plt.show()
```

on the produced plot, the ticks on the axes are simply the values dictated by extent kwarg in plt.imshow and not the nice scientific notation 10**n I would like it to have.
Any idea why it's misbehaving? Thank you

Comment: could you post this as a minimum working example that people can actually reproduce using their computer?

Comment: this script does work. I don't understand your request

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_Working_Example might help. the problem is that you load some files other people don't have so they cannot just run your code.

Comment: right, good point! (oops) I'm editing the code above. now imshow simply an uses an empty 2D array but it serves the purpose, i.e. show that ticklabel_format does not work. thank you for your suggestions

Comment: according to the documentation (see http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.ticklabel_format) the sci format is only used for values larger than 10, which makes sense. how do you want to represent 2 more scientifically?

Comment: Ok, now I get it: the imshow extent argument is in logscale, i.e. the original values were obtained from a grid [numpy.logscale(-2.,2.),numpy.logscale(5.,9.)]. Because of this, ticklabel_format has no effect. Makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

Just use `matplotlib.pyplot.ylim` or `matplotlib.pyplot.xlim` to set the limits.